# Circular reference involving containing bean 'XXX' - consider declaring the factory method as static for independence from its containing instance

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-rest

I am creating two projects ***globalDB*** and ***GlobalWeb*** using spring. I want to create multiple database connections in ***GlobalWeb***, Jdbc properties are fetched from ***GlobalDB*** project dao layer at the time of ***GlobalWeb*** initiation. When i run the global web, Am getting the following exception.

> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'globalWebConfig': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: com.kla.it.dao.Dao com.kla.it.global.conf.GlobalWebConfig.dao; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'daoImpl': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate com.kla.it.dao.impl.DaoImpl.template; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'template' defined in class path resource [com/kla/it/database/DatabaseConfig.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor argument with index 0 of type [javax.sql.DataSource]: : Error creating bean with name 'partsDs' defined in com.kla.it.global.conf.GlobalWebConfig: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource]: Circular reference involving containing bean 'globalWebConfig' - consider declaring the factory method as static for independence from its containing instance. Factory method 'getPartsDataSource' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'partsDs' defined in com.kla.it.global.conf.GlobalWebConfig: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource]: Circular reference involving containing bean 'globalWebConfig' - consider declaring the factory method as static for independence from its containing instance. Factory method 'getPartsDataSource' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:334)
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1214)
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543)
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:305)
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:301)
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:196)
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:772)
>           at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:834)
>           at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:537)
>           at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:446)
>           at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:328)
>           at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:107)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4680)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5143)
>           at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:717)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:690)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:705)

***GlobalDB configuration class***

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.kla.it")
@PropertySource(value = {"classpath:database.properties"})
public class DatabaseConfig {

    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

//    @Bean(name="ds")
    public DataSource getDataSource(){
        System.out.println("++++++++++++++++DATABASE++++++++++++++START++++++++++++");
        System.out.println("Method to crate data source");
        DriverManagerDataSource ds = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        ds.setDriverClassName("net.snowflake.client.jdbc.SnowflakeDriver");
        ds.setUrl(env.getRequiredProperty("db.url"));
        ds.setUsername(env.getRequiredProperty( "db.username"));
        ds.setPassword(env.getRequiredProperty( "db.password"));
        return ds;
    }

    @Bean(name="template")
    public JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate(DataSource ds) {
        System.out.println("Jdbc template method called.");
        JdbcTemplate template = new JdbcTemplate(ds);
        template.setResultsMapCaseInsensitive(true);
        System.out.println("++++++++++++++++DATABASE++++++++++++++END+++++++++++");
        return template;
    }
}
```

***GlobalDB Dao Layer class***

```
@Repository
@Qualifier("dao")
public class DaoImpl implements Dao{

    @Autowired
    JdbcTemplate template;
  @Override
    public Map<String, String> getConnectionsData(String appName, String env) {

        List<Map<String, Object>> reportsList = new ArrayList<>();
        Map<String, String> dataSourceMap = new HashMap<>();
        String qry = "SELECT * FROM DB_CONFIG WHERE name = '"+appName+"' AND ev = '"+env+"'";
         reportsList = template.queryForList(qry);
            int count = 1;
            for (Map<String, Object> map : reportsList) {
                dataSourceMap.put(String.valueOf(map.get("prop")), String.valueOf(map.get("val")));
            }
        return dataSourceMap;

    }
}
```

***GlobalWeb Config class***

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.kla.it")
@PropertySource(value = {"classpath:global.properties"})
public class GlobalWebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired(required=true)
    Dao dao;

     @Bean(name = "partsDs")
     public DriverManagerDataSource getPartsDataSource(){
        Map<String, String> dsMap = dao.getConnectionsData("parts", "dev");
        DriverManagerDataSource partsDs= new DriverManagerDataSource();
        partsDs.setDriverClassName(dsMap.get("driver"));
        partsDs.setUrl(dsMap.get("url"));
        partsDs.setUsername(dsMap.get("user"));
        partsDs.setPassword(dsMap.get("password"));   
        return partsDs;
    }

     @Bean(name = "cosmosDs")
      public DriverManagerDataSource getCosmosDataSource(){
        Map<String, String> dsMap = dao.getConnectionsData("cosmos", "dev");
        DriverManagerDataSource cosmosDs = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        cosmosDs.setDriverClassName(dsMap.get("driver"));
        cosmosDs.setUrl(dsMap.get("url"));
        cosmosDs.setUsername(dsMap.get("user"));
        cosmosDs.setPassword(dsMap.get("password"));   
        return cosmosDs;
    }

      @Bean(name = "itsDs")
       public DataSource getITSDataSource(){
        Map<String, String> dsMap = dao.getConnectionsData("ITSecurity", "dev");
        DriverManagerDataSource itsDs= new DriverManagerDataSource();
        itsDs.setDriverClassName(dsMap.get("driver"));
        itsDs.setUrl(dsMap.get("url"));
        itsDs.setUsername(dsMap.get("user"));
        itsDs.setPassword(dsMap.get("password"));   
        return itsDs;
    }

    @Bean(name = "sfPartsDB")
    public JdbcTemplate snowFlakeParts() {
        System.out.println("Jdbc template method called.");
        DataSource cosmosDs = getPartsDataSource();
        JdbcTemplate sfPartsDB = new JdbcTemplate(cosmosDs);
        sfPartsDB.setResultsMapCaseInsensitive(true);
        return sfPartsDB;
    }

    @Bean(name = "sfCosmosDB")
    public JdbcTemplate snowFlakeCosmos() {
        System.out.println("Jdbc template method called.");
        DataSource cosmosDs = getCosmosDataSource();
        JdbcTemplate sfCosmosDB = new JdbcTemplate(cosmosDs);
        sfCosmosDB.setResultsMapCaseInsensitive(true);
        return sfCosmosDB;
    }
//    
    @Bean(name = "oracleDB")
    public JdbcTemplate oracleTemplate() {
        DataSource itsDs = getITSDataSource();
        JdbcTemplate oracleDB = new JdbcTemplate(itsDs);
        oracleDB.setResultsMapCaseInsensitive(true);
        return oracleDB;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try with below code. It works!!
 
1. @Qualifier to particular datasource reference(by name).
2. @Import Aggregate all the configuration classes.

```
    @Configuration
    @ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.kla.it")
    @PropertySource(value = {"classpath:database.properties"})
    public class DatabaseConfig {

        @Autowired
        private Environment env;

        @Bean(name="ds")
        public DataSource getDataSource(){
            System.out.println("++++++++++++++++DATABASE++++++++++++++START++++++++++++");
            System.out.println("Method to crate data source");
            DriverManagerDataSource ds = new DriverManagerDataSource();
            ds.setDriverClassName("net.snowflake.client.jdbc.SnowflakeDriver");
            ds.setUrl(env.getRequiredProperty("db.url"));
            ds.setUsername(env.getRequiredProperty( "db.username"));
            ds.setPassword(env.getRequiredProperty( "db.password"));
            return ds;
        }

        @Bean(name="template")
        public JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate(@Qualifier("ds")DataSource ds) {
            System.out.println("Jdbc template method called.");
            JdbcTemplate template = new JdbcTemplate(ds);
            template.setResultsMapCaseInsensitive(true);
            System.out.println("++++++++++++++++DATABASE++++++++++++++END+++++++++++");
            return template;
        }
    }   


@Import(DatabaseConfig.class) /* add this line to aggrgate java configuration classes*/
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScanenter code here(basePackages = "com.kla.it")
@PropertySource(value = {"classpath:global.properties"})
public class GlobalWebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
}
```

Comment: Thanks Bala Venkatesh Koripalli, It is working fine.